# I recently upgraded my laravel project from 5.5 to 10 and now i am getting Cross-Origin Request Blocked error

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vite

I recently upgraded my project from Laravel 5.5 to 10 and as part of upgrade am no longer using laravel mix and i am using vite. After running `npm run dev` when i load pages i get Cross-Origin Request Blocked

[image]

Comment: you should implement allowing cors origin to specific URLs (your frontend URL) or all URLs (not recommended), here is a tutorial to implement this https://dev.to/keikesu0122/a-simple-way-to-enable-cors-on-laravel-55i#:~:text=The%20simplest%20method%20to%20enable,%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fhogehoge.com%20.